# What is the purpose of thing sub-function returning __repr__ with f str

Tags: python, flask, repr

Trying to understand the purpose of `__repr__` in a sub function. The class that is called is for db.model in flask I do not see how this function gets used and what its purposes. This is a link to the git hub in which I came across this https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Python/Flask_Blog/08-Posts/flaskblog/models.py

This code creates the table in MySQL for a flask website.

I have researched the purpose of `__repr__` however I still cannot understand how it works in this context.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    #posts = db.relationship('Aaa', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

There is no error message but I do not understand the context in which this is used.

Comment: `__repr__` is mostly for quick debugging, a-la `print(user)`

Comment: __repr__ is for programmer purpose while __str__ for the user purpose. When you call __repr__ with f-string is just a easier way to format the output string in the __repr__ format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **repr** method is used to get a string representation of a Python object. It is common to find people using it when creating models for their flask app.

With the **repr** method, you can make a query from the database and print the result of the query. Instead of getting the location of the query object in memory, the **repr** method provides a better representation of the result.

Using your example:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    #posts = db.relationship('Aaa', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

If you have a user with the following details:

- id = 1
- first_name = 'Billy'
- username = 'Bly'
- email = 'Billyjoe@bj.com'
- image_file = 'default.jpg'
- password = 'sample'

On printing the result from the query, you will get:

```
"User('Bly', 'Billyjoe@bj.com', 'default.jpg')"
```

The result above is better than something that looks like:

```
<__main__.User object at 0x7f6882314da0>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this gives me the insight I was looking for in terms of the context to how it was used.

Answer (score 1):

`__repr__` is a built in function that can represent your object as some pre-defined string whenever you call to it. For example:

```
class Hi():
    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting = 'Hello how are you'

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Hi, I am an object who greets'


h = Hi()

print(h)
```

when I print `h` it shows me:

```
>>>Hi, I am an object who greets
```

If you don't have a `__repr__` function, so:

```
class Hi():
    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting = 'Hello how are you'


h = Hi()

print(h)
```

This prints:

```
>>><__main__.Hi object at 0x102e3e7b8>
```

It's used for debugging because `<__main__.Hi object at 0x102e3e7b8>` can be ambiguous and `__repr__` gets rid of the ambiguity.